# How to convert dictionary values to different elements of xml using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following line generated from my code:-

```
<elements>
  <name>Mammal</name>
  <table_category>
    <val>['Animal', 'Fish', 'Bird', 'Human']</val>
  </table_category>
</elements>
<elements>
  <name>Reptile</name>
  <table_category>
    <val>['Animal', 'Fish']</val>
  </table_category>
</elements>
```

['Animal', 'Fish', 'Bird', 'Human'] are values from dictionary for particular key Mammal.

I want ouput like this:-

```
<elements>
  <name>Mammal</name>
  <table_category>
    <val>Animal</val>
    <val>Fish</val>
    <val>Bird</val>
    <val>Human</val>
  </table_category>
</elements>
<elements>
  <name>Reptile</name>
  <table_category>
    <val>Animal</val>
    <val>Fish</val>
  </table_category>
</elements>
```

I am using python, I tried using for i in range(0,len) but it's not splitting properly and gives out of index. Please suggest how to do it using python 3+?

Comment: Can you post your code as opposed to just the desired output?

Comment: Can you add your dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you get list of category somewhere in your code, try below code

```
l1 = ['Animal', 'Fish', 'Bird', 'Human']
s1 = "</val>\n<val>".join(l1)
s1 = "<val>%s</val>"%s1
print s1
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: in your code you are getting the list of category i.e. ['Animal', 'Fish', 'Bird', 'Human'] so you can add above lines there and generate the value tag for each record in the list and put it in the xml